# Redigo type of value returned from GET

Tags: redis, redigo

I'd like to be able to GET a value of a key and immediately know what type it is. I'm using

```golang
res, err := conn.Do("GET", key)
```

This returns an `interface{}` in `res`. Depending on the type, I'd like to call one of the helper functions like `redigo.String(res)` or `redigo.Bool(res)`. I know I can do `conn.Do("TYPE", key)` to get the type separately, but how can I get the type just from the result of one GET request?

Comment: Honestly my first thought here is work to control the input pipeline and guarantee the key type.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, REDIS `TYPE` command does not provide you the details of value type it just tells you whether the key's value is a string, list, set, zset, hash, or stream.

So your application code or client code must identify what's it's equivalent for your programming language.

You can try to decode your data using the known key value types.